# Does there exist a Turing complete typed lambda calculus?

Tags: computability, lambda-calculus, type-theory

Do there exist any Turing complete typed lambda calculi? If so, what are a few examples?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255413/how-did-haskell-add-turing-completeness-to-system-f and http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29519/what-functions-can-system-f-not-compute

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, sure. Many typed lambda calculi accept only [strongly normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_property_%28lambda-calculus%29) terms, by design, so they cannot express arbitrary computations. But a type system can be anything you like; make it broad enough, and you can express all deterministic computations.

A trivial type system that encompasses a Turing-complete fragment of the lambda calculus is the one that accepts every term as well-typed (with a [top type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type)).
$$\dfrac{}{\Gamma \vdash M : \top}$$

More practically, statically typed functional programming languages have at their core a typed lambda calculus which allows a [fixpoint combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) as well-typed. For example, start with the [simply typed lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus) (or the ML type system or [system F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) or any other type system of your choice) and add a rule that makes some fixpoint combinator like $\mathbf{Y} = \lambda f. (\lambda x. f (x\,x)) (\lambda x. f (x\,x))$ well-typed.
$$
  \dfrac{\Gamma \vdash f : T \rightarrow T}
        {\Gamma \vdash \mathbf{Y}\,f : T}
  \qquad
  \dfrac{\Gamma \vdash f : T \rightarrow T}
        {\Gamma \vdash (\lambda x. f (x\,x)) (\lambda x. f (x\,x)) : T}
$$
The rules as presented above are rather clumsy, as they make terms like $\mathbf{Y}\,f$ well-typed even though their constituents are not well-typed — they are not fully compositional. A simple fix is to add a fixpoint combinator as a language constant and provide a delta rule for it; then it is a simple matter to have a type system and reduction semantics with [type preservation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_reduction). You do get away from the pure lambda calculus into the realm of lambda calculus with constants.
$$\begin{gather*}
  \dfrac{}{\Gamma \vdash \textbf{fix} : (T \rightarrow T) \rightarrow T} \\
  \textbf{fix}\,f \to f (\textbf{fix}\,f) \\
\end{gather*}$$

Sticking to the pure lambda calculus, an interesting type system is the lambda calculus with intersection types.

$$
\dfrac{\Gamma \vdash M : T_1 \quad \Gamma \vdash M : T_2}
      {\Gamma \vdash M : T_1 \wedge T_2}
      (\wedge I)
\qquad\qquad
\dfrac{}
      {\Gamma \vdash M : \top}
      (\top I)
$$

Intersection types have interesting properties with respect to normalization:

- A lambda-term can be typed without using the $\top I$ rule iff it is strongly normalizing.
- A lambda-term admits a type not containing $\top$ iff it has a normal form.

See [Characterization of lambda-terms that have union types](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62/characterization-of-lambda-terms-that-have-union-types/88#88) for an insight as to why intersection types have such a remarkable scope.

So you have a type system that defines a Turing-complete language (since every term is well-typed), and a simple characterization of terminating computations. Of course, since this type system characterizes normalization, it is not decidable.

<sub>A remark on the rule names $(\top I)$ and $(\wedge I)$: they have no formal meaning, but they are chosen deliberately. the $I$ stands for “introduction”, because these are introduction rules — they introduce the symbol ($\wedge$ or $\top$) into the type below the line. Dually, you'll find elimination rules, when a symbol appears above the line but not below. For example, the rule to typecheck a lambda expression in the simply-typed lambda calculus is the introduction rule for $\rightarrow$, and the rule to typecheck an application is the elimination rule for $\rightarrow$.</sub>