# Is there any type system which can assign a type to any halting lambda calculus term?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus, type-theory

Some lambda terms, such as the church number 3: `(f x -> (f (f (f x))))`, are easily typeable on the simply typed lambda calculus. Others, such as `pred`, `(a b c d e f -> (d (g -> (t -> (t (g e)))) (g -> f) (g -> g)))`, are known to require more complex systems such as System-F. Some of them aren't typeable on System-F itself, as this [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879944/why-haskell-doesnt-accept-my-combinatoric-zip-definition) I posted in another question. As [András Kovács observed on the follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885983/infinite-type-error-when-defining-zip-with-foldr-only-can-it-be-fixed/), that function can be typed in Agda, although the technique he used for doing so isn't trivial.

I have a lot of similarly tricky terms such as `nTuple = (k -> (k (b c d -> (b (e -> (c e d)))) (b -> b) (b -> b)))`, which receives a church number and returns an N-Tuple of that length. I don't know if those terms are typeable. I would like to know:

1. Some systems seems to ban many "desirable" terms, while others bans less of those. What is the property of a system that determines if it is more accepting or more restricting?
2. Is there any type system in which arbitrary lambda terms are typeable?
3. Is there any general technique/algorithm to find the types of those expressions in such system?

Comment: `Some systems seem to ban many "desirable" terms, while others ban less of those.` Yes, type systems are a trade off. In an untyped system (e.g. JavaScript, untyped Scheme, etc.) you __can__ write any __"incorrect"__ program. The onus of writing __"correct"__ programs is on the programmer. A type system removes this onus by disallowing certain __"incorrect"__ expressions. However, type systems also disallow certain __"correct"__ expressions in favor of simplicity. As type systems become more powerful, they disallow fewer __"correct"__ expressions but they also become more complicated.

Comment: @AaditMShah: I'll come out and say that if you can't type your term in dependent type theory, there's little reason to believe that it is correct  by any criteria. Type theory is expressive enough to be a foundation for *mathematics in general*; and by what means could we accept any argument about a program's correctness if not by mathematical reasoning?

Comment: @AndrásKovács does that mean there is probably a type for any of my "useful" terms, or that those "useful" terms are under some sense "wrong"?

Comment: In general, if they're total then there should be a type for them. There are some esoteric exceptions to this (for example, no total language can implement its [own interpreter](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2003-May/004343.html), by a version of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem), but I believe it's a fair general rule.

Comment: @AaditMShah your example is easily typeable even in [Haskell](http://lpaste.net/135705), and there's a [package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-aligned) for it.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Today I learned something new. Thank you for proving me wrong. =)

Comment: You ask four questions, one in the title and three in the body. Please focus on *one*. As for the question in the title, no, [because the set of all total recursive functions is not enumerable](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/266/why-are-the-total-functions-not-enumerable).

Comment: That's quite a broad question here, but I think http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/does-there-exist-a-turing-complete-typed-lambda-calculus/2639#2639 should cover it.

Comment: @Raphael The answer to the title is “yes”. If it was changed to “type system that assigns a type to all halting terms and only halting terms”, it would still be “yes”. If it was changed to “**decidable** type system that assigns a type to all halting terms and **only** halting terms”, it would be “no”.

Comment: @Gilles Right, thanks for clearing that up. (I think semi-decidability is enough to make the answer "no", isn't it?)